# TBXML and <?xml> tag problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ipad, tbxml

this is my problem:

I am using TBXML in my iPad app. The XML server responses start with the xml description line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

and TBXML is not able to parse the nodes (i.e nextSibling methods are getting null). Converting the XML to a string to remove the line is not an option as I am using a NSData object directly with the tbxmlWithXMLData() method to create my TBXML objects.

What can I do to make TBXML understand my XML?  Of if not, is there any way to remove that line from the NSData?

Thanks all.

Comment: I thought a ?xml line worked fine for me, but I can't remember for sure.  Is there anything in the logs?  Does any node work?  Perhaps you can serialize back to xml to see if anything is there.

Comment: @Peter DeWeese> I can get the root node, but not its attributes or child nodes. The logs are not showing any problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the xml declaration (`<?xml...?>`) is what's causing the problem? Are there any spaces before the `<?xml...?>`?

Comment: - It looks like I was touching the NSMutableData with some wrong lines before load it into my TBXLM objects. All is working fine now. 
Thank you all.

Comment: @gabriel mendez, Please add that answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It looks like I was adding some blank spaces before load the XML in the TBXLM objects. I removed the spaces and all is working fine now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

can you write here your code? 
Also with the xml (a part of it, of course)... I used TBXML a lot of times, and I hadn't problems with the xml declaration!

Answer (score 0):

Where is the XML coming from? Because if you created it yourself and it is local, you can use Dashcode to make the necessary adjustments for XMLs.